# Proguard rules for Linphone Android that enabled proguard in build.gradle

Tags: android, java-native-interface, proguard, linphone

Is there a good setting for Linphone android that proguard enabled in build.gradle, I try this code in proguard-rules.pro :

```
-keep public class * extends *
-keep public class * implements LinphoneCoreListener
-keep interface * { *; }
```

but JNI error was showed :

> JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: JNI GetMethodID called with pending
>   exception 'java.lang.NoSuchMethodError' thrown in long
>   org.linphone.core.LinphoneCoreImpl.newLinphoneCore(org.linphone.core.LinphoneCoreListener,
>   java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.Object):-2

is there somebody, who have a good setting for linphone proguard ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please add below code to your proguard-android.txt file

```
#linphone
-keep class org.linphone.** { *; }
-keepattributes Signature
```

Hope It will help.!